# Using quick.db to store username change history

Tags: discord.js, quick.db

So I know this is possible because I've seen some bots do it, including logger bot where it shows all previous username change history if someone joins your server, or when you trigger a command such as -username @somediscord it fetches the audit logs if not then fetches all the recent changes or old ones according to what your db history has. If anyone could help out providing a code for it, I'll be grateful for you. I'm using discord.js v11.5 if anyone is asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If I were going to recreate this, I would filter user changes to only show tag/name changes. Then, in a database, for that User ID add the new name to a list.